# Десериализация json в Dictionary

Tags: c#, json.net

Хочу десериализоваьь json-файл в Dictionary. Сначала получаю ссылку с сервера, а потом делаю как на сайте Newtonsoft.com deserialising Dictionary, но вылетает исключение

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value @.Path:line 0 position 0.

Пытался исправить добавлением к строке кавычки и знака @, но ошибка та же

```
using (var webClient = new System.Net.webClient(){Encoding=Encoding.UTF8})
{
JObject json = JObject.Parse(webClient.DownloadString(MyUrl));
 string json = "@\"" + json + "\""; //не работает ни с этой строкой, ни без неё 
 Dictionary<string, string> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,string>>(newjson);
 }
```

Вот json-файл:

```
{ 
"response": {
    "status": "ok",
    "data": {
        "30": {
            "title": "London",
            "Country": "Britain"
        },
        "24": {
            "title": "Paris",
            "Country": "France"
        }
    },
    "count": 2
}}
```

Нужно, чтобы я мог получить связку страна-город

Comment: `Dictionary<string,string>` это ключ - значение, а ваш `json` же имеет посложнее структуру, скопируйте `json` буфер обмена и  в `visual-studio` нажмите `edit - paste special - paste json as classes` и оно вам вставит структуру классов в которую можно будет десериализовать данный `json`

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych не очень понятно, что делать после того, как json разделился на классы, что передавать в качестве аргумента?

Comment: десереализируйте свой `json` в полученый класс и юзайте

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych получится два класса:класс "3 со свойствами title и country и "24", как какое-то общее правило для них сделать?

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych "30", а не "3"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Связку "Страна-Город" можно получить так:

```
var json = JObject.Parse(str);
var result = json["response"]?["data"]?
       .Select(s => new
       {
           Country = s.First?["Country"]?.ToString(),
           City = s.First?["title"]?.ToString()
       })
       .ToDictionary(k => k.Country, v => v.City) ?? 
        new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

---

Получить данные в формате "Лондон -30", "Париж - 24".

```
var result = json["response"]?["data"]?
           .Select(s => new
            {
               Number = (s as JProperty)?.Name,
               City = s.First?["title"]?.ToString()
            })
            .ToDictionary(k => k.City, v => v.Number) ?? 
            new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

Comment: Спасибо! То, что нужно

Comment: а если нужно получить связку "город-вышестоящий класс", то есть Лондон -30, Париж - 24?

Comment: @NickShepard обновил ответ.

Comment: Сердечно благодарю!

Answer (score 1):

Вот примерно так у меня получилось разобрать ваш `json` :

Структура классов :

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Response response { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, CountryClass> data { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; }
}

public class CountryClass
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

Десериализация :

```
string json = "{\"response\": {\"status\": \"ok\",\"data\": {\"30\": {\"title\": \"London\",\"Country\": \"Britain\"},\"24\": {\"title\": \"Paris\",\"Country\": \"France\"}},\"count\": 2}}";
Rootobject values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);
```